# How to get a ScrollViewer to be an exact height *and* show both scrollbars at all times?

Tags: xaml, datagrid, scrollviewer

I have a **DataGrid** inside a **ScrollViewer**.

I want the whole thing to only be **200** pixels high.

But this code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="DataGridArea" Height="200">
    <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FieldChanges}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

produces this with the scrollbar only on the **right** side:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/8lhu03.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/8lhu03.png)

and I can only see the scrollbar when I scroll **down** to the bottom:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/a9oikp.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/a9oikp.png)

**What do I have to do so that my ScrollViewer is 200 pixels high AND both scrollbars are present at all times?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `HorisontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Visible` on the `ScrollViewer` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the height of the ScrollViewer's content (the DataGrid).